# Change background image when hover hover over div with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

HTML setup

[image]

I have a setup like in the picture. I want users to hover over each red box and when the mouse is over each box, I want the background (which is now grey) to change in to a background picture. Different pics with different box. In my css I have:

```
#service {
background: grey;}
```

I wrote this jQuery code:

```
$service = $('#service');
$('.service-list').on('mouseover', 'div', function() {
    $service.css('background-image', 'url(' + $(this).attr("data-uri") + ')');
});
```

but it's not working. I also want the background pics to preload because they are around 650kb so its smooth and instantaneous. I was going to make a div called preload and then do

```
<img src="path/image-01.png" width="1" height="1" alt="Image 01" />
```

and then do preload display none.. Idk if that will work. please help

edit----
just to be clear,
I want to change the background of the services div background, not each of the red box background

Comment: It'd be much better if you created a jsfiddle or a live demo we can look at?

Comment: why not simply use CSS for hover? its a lot easier

Comment: If you want to use jQuery instead of CSS for something particular you could try .hover(): https://api.jquery.com/hover/

Comment: background of the box or of the whole page?

Comment: I want to change the background of the services div background, not each of the red box background

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by jquery hover function.

```
$service = $('#service');

$('.greay-box').hover(function() {
    $service.css('background-image', 'url(' + $(this).attr("data-uri") + ')');
        }, function(){

    $service.css('background-image', '');

    });
```

Here is a example [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/689xod67/2/). Hope this helps you.

Comment: just to be clear, I want to change the background of the services div background, not each of the red box background

Answer (score 0):

Hey I HOpe You Are Looking Something like this try to alter the image . using Jquery

```js
var sourceSwap = function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        var newSource = $this.data('alt-src');
        $this.data('alt-src', $this.attr('src'));
        $this.attr('src', newSource);
    }

    $(function () {
        $('img.xyz').hover(sourceSwap, sourceSwap);
    });
```

```css
    .my {
        width:100px;
        height:100px;    
        overflow:hidden;
         border: 2px solid red;
          float:left; 
          padding:2px;
          margin:2px;
        
    }
    .my img {
        min-width:100%;
        max-width:100%;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <body>


<div class="row">

<div class="my">
   <img class="xyz" data-alt-src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/5d/63/2e/5d632ede715b92de1c2db866029282b5.jpg" src="http://wall-papers.info/images/grey-background-wallpaper/grey-background-wallpaper-23.jpg" />
</div>
<div class="my">
   <img class="xyz" data-alt-src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/5d/63/2e/5d632ede715b92de1c2db866029282b5.jpg" src="http://wall-papers.info/images/grey-background-wallpaper/grey-background-wallpaper-23.jpg" />
</div>
<div class="my">
   <img class="xyz" data-alt-src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/fa/11/c2/fa11c23eddc07d0dd8b26432750df85e.jpg" src="http://wall-papers.info/images/grey-background-wallpaper/grey-background-wallpaper-23.jpg" />
</div>
<div class="my">
   <img class="xyz" data-alt-src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/fa/11/c2/fa11c23eddc07d0dd8b26432750df85e.jpg" src="http://wall-papers.info/images/grey-background-wallpaper/grey-background-wallpaper-23.jpg" />
</div>
</div>

  </body>
    </html>
```

Can Check The fiddle Also. . .
[UPDATED FIDDLE DEMO LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/Z47JT/1307/)

Comment: just to be clear, I want to change the background of the services div background, not each of the red box background

Comment: hello check the updated fiddle i used service_list for image class 1 and 4 no div will show image and 3,4 will not